# asp.net link button doesn't work in web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a simple link button in my aspx page. everything works perfect, but once i upload my web forms to web server I have the following error for link button

```
CS1061: 'ASP.ourproducts_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnShowBrandsDiv_Click' and no extension method 'btnShowBrandsDiv_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.ourproducts_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

i have a definition for my button in both .CS and .designer pages, or it won't work in my local machine
this is my button

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnShowBrandsDiv" OnClick="btnShowBrandsDiv_Click">Show</asp:LinkButton>
```

it maybe a very simple thing but i couldn't figure it out.

thank you

Comment: It looks like a deployment issue. How are you uploading your website to server?

Comment: maybe you are missing a dll file? Also is this a "website" or a "web application" project?

Comment: it's a web application. @Ehsan it's not me who uploads the site, what is the deployment issue could i have?
 thanks all

Comment: Are you publishing the website before deploying? or just copying all the files to server with code files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server doesn't have an updated version of your DLL.  Copy up your bin directory to your server and .NET will be able to find the definition.